# CakePHP Case Insensitive Find

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any way to perform a case-insensitive lookup in CakePHP? e.g. is something like the following possible?

```
$record = $this->find(
    'first', 
    array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'name' => $name,
           'ignore-case' => true
        )
    )
);
```

I'm using CakePHP 1.3, if that matters (yes I know it's outdated, but I don't have the time to migrate it just yet.)

Comment: change the db collate to `_ci`

Comment: That should actually be the default IMO - for most applications it does not make sense to use case sensitive tables/fields.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best approach, but one possibility is:

```
    $record = $this->find(
         'first', 
         array(
              'conditions' => array(
              'LOWER(Model.name)' => strtolower($name)
             )
         )
     );
```

Comment: Or just use the correct collation as outlined in the comment above => fixed at the root of the issue instead of fighting the symptoms.